# How to Stop Broadcast receiver from other activity

Tags: android

I am making a Application in which I want to stop a broadcast receiver onDelete method of widget provider class.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:-

```
 PackageManager pm  = Re_editActivity.this.getPackageManager();
 ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(currentActivity.this, name_of_your_receiver.class);
 pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

for more info see below link:-

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-broadcast-receiver-enable-and.html